# AWK regex for gsubs pattern

Tags: regex, awk

I am trying to define a gsub awk statement to find all non escaped $ chars and escape them.

so following input -> results should be handled:

```
$ -> \$
$a -> \$a
\$ -> \$
$$$ -> \$\$\$
```

So basically I am looking for the correct pattern to put in this statement:

```
gsub(pattern,"\\\$", input_string);
```

Comment: What have you tried? Why isn't it working? What is your question? Is it necessary to do this using awk, or would a Perl solution be acceptable?

Comment: I need to use a gsubs( search pattern, "substitution", input_string); command in awk.

Comment: hi i just did - please check

Comment: What about `\\$` (i.e. an escaped backslash followed by an unescaped `$`)?

Comment: @NicholasAntimisiaris: Without some sample input and expected output, it is not easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Using `$` as a Field separator, awk splits the input and it would add a backslash at the end only if the string is empty or ends with any character but not of a backslash character.

```
$ cat file
$
$a$$$
\$
$$$\$$
$ awk -F$ -v OFS="$" '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++){if($i == "" || $i ~/[^\\]$/) $i=$i"\\"}}1' file
\$
\$a\$\$\$
\$
\$\$\$\$\$
```

You could also try the below perl solution.

```
perl -pe 's/(?<!\\)\$/\\\$/g' file
```

The substitution matches all `$` that are not preceded by backslash and adds a backslash before them. The backslashes themselves all need escaping, as does the `$`, as it has a special meaning in regular expressions.

Comment: I'd already written the exact same Perl solution but was waiting for the OP to make an effort.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I'm in the middle of writing explanation for that perl solution but you done that.

Comment: Please see updated description - I need a pattern for an awk gsub function call if possible. Thanks for responding.

Comment: Why you rely on `gsub` function?

Comment: you may consider this `awk -F$ -v OFS="$" '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++){if($i == "" || $i ~/[^\\]$/) gsub(/$/, "\\", $i)}}1' file`